# "June honourees" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was solving a crossword recently and one of the questions was "June honourees". The supposed answer was "dads". Could someone tell me why is that so?

Comment: Father's Day in the US is the third Sunday in June.

Comment: @StoneyB Wouldn't those be *honorees*? ;-)

Comment: Maybe a Canadian crossword puzzle?  They expect their readers to know about Father's Day (US custom) and to use the spelling *honour* (UK custom).

Comment: The third Sunday in June is Father’s Day in about 90 countries, including Canada and the UK.

Comment: The original question (from the crossword) employs the spelling "honorees". I usually use British English, so the word was automatically corrected in my head. I apologize for a little confusion.=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Father's day is celebrated by Americans on the third Sunday in June.

**June honourees** means

- "those who are to be honored in June", "those who receive an honour or award in June"

> - [**to honor**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/honor) -  (hono**u**r - Chief. Br.) to give special recognition to : to confer honor on

- From the web: Highlights from the event are incorporated into the year's Academy Awards show. [**The 2017 honorees**](http://www.oscars.org/governors) are: Charles Burnett, Owen Roizman, Donald Sutherland and Agnès Varda.